# Sql Result Set Mapping with non-entity

Tags: java, jpa, eclipselink

Is it possible to have map a JPA 2.x sql result set mapping to a non-entity?  I haven't seen any documentation for this.  Currently we are using EclipseLink 2.5 and classpath scanning.  I'm also interested, if there is an alternative way to define in the persistence.xml?  Here is an exmaple...

```
package com.example.model

@SqlResultMapping(name = "nonpojoentity", class= { 
     @ConstructorResult(targetClass = MyNonEntityPojo.class, columns = {
      ...
     }) 
})
@NamedNativeQueries(values = {
   @NamedNativeQuery(name="...", query = "...", resultSetMapping = "nonpojoentity"
})
public class MyNonEntityPojo implements Serializable {
  ....
}
```

So unless I place @Entity on the MyNonEntityPojo class EclipseLink does not recognize it.  The problem is ... It's not an entity, and if I were to do any sort of ddl generation from my code it would be incorrect.  Thoughts?  Has anyone else solved this problem?

Comment: Persistence annotations should be put on entities and classes picked up in the persistence unit.  You might get it to work by listing your class explicitly in the persistence.xml file

Comment: I had the same problem. As far as auto-dicovery goes, Chris is right and I don't know about putting it the persistence.xml

DDL generation :  I use Hibernate as JPA implementation and the schema generator does NOT pick it up when generating DDL. So it turns out to be a non-issue for DDL generation. I don't know if EclipseLink knows to skip these classes when generating DDL.

Comment: Don't you think there should be some sort of annotation say maybe @NonEntity or such that would allow for this same autowiring, yet keep your data model in tack?